# Images in WPF getting blurry

Tags: c#, wpf, image

im trying to make something in WPF but i have one problem. Ive placed some elements to the window so in editor it looks thus:

[image]

In build it looks thus:

[image]

And if i place to element->

```
RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
```

In build it look now:

[image]

I really dont know how to solve it so i will be really grateful that someone will help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually related to not having `SnapsToDevicePixels` set.

[Pixel Snapping in WPF Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

In your control or window, you can set it by doing

```
<MyControl SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
```

> The WPF graphics system uses device-independent units to enable
> resolution and device independence. Each device independent pixel
> automatically scales with the system's dots per inch (dpi) setting.
> This provides WPF applications proper scaling for different dpi
> settings and makes the application automatically dpi-aware.
>
> However,
> this dpi independence can create irregular edge rendering due to
> anti-aliasing. These artifacts, commonly seen as blurry, or
> semi-transparent, edges can occur when the location of an edge falls
> in the middle of a device pixel rather than between device pixels. To
> address this issue, WPF provides a way for object edges in a visual
> tree to snap, or become fixed, to device pixels through pixel
> snapping, eliminating the semi-transparent edges produced by
> anti-aliasing.
>
> Pixel snapping is a means to suppress these visual
> artifacts by applying small offsets to the geometry of the visual to
> align the geometry to device pixels.

Comment: @UareBugged Great. That bites everyone initially.

Comment: Hi, WPF CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap() cause also image blurry. Do you know? plz.